# Error running jasmine-jquery in grunt-contrib-jasmine task

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine-jquery, grunt-contrib-jasmine

I'm attempting to use jasmine-jquery in my  unit tests to test BackboneJS Views but i'm getting the following error when I try to run the tests:

> > Running "jasmine:src" (jasmine) task
> >
> > Testing jasmine specs via PhantomJS
> >
> > TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'jasmine.spiedEventsKey = function (selector, eventName) {
> >         return [$(selector).selector, eventName].toString()
> >       }') at
> >
> > test/vendor/jasmine-jquery-master/lib/jasmine-jquery.js:40
> >
> > test/vendor/jasmine-jquery-master/lib/jasmine-jquery.js:34
> >
> > test/vendor/jasmine-jquery-master/lib/jasmine-jquery.js:838

I'm using grunt, phantomjs, grunt-contrib-jasmine task and grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs.

This is my grunt config

```
    jasmine : {
        src : 'lib/**/*.js',
        options : {
            vendor: [
                'test/vendor/Sinon/sinon-1.14.1.js',
                'test/vendor/jasmine-jquery-master/vendor/jquery/jquery.js',
                'test/vendor/jasmine-jquery-master/lib/jasmine-jquery.js'
            ],
            specs: 'test/spec/**/*.js',
            helpers: 'test/helpers/**/*.js',
            template: require('grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs'),
            templateOptions: {
                requireConfigFile: 'lib/js/main.js',
                requireConfig: {
                    baseUrl: './lib/js/',
                    paths: {
                        'app': 'app',
                        'router': 'router',
                        'text': './text-master/text',
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Have I set this up incorrectly or am I simply unable to run jasmine-jquery headlessly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. Fixed it by including frameworks in a different order in my `karma.conf.js` file.

wrong:

```
frameworks: ['phantomjs-shim', 'jasmine', 'jasmine-jquery']
```

correct:

```
frameworks: ['phantomjs-shim', 'jasmine-jquery', 'jasmine']
```